# PHP - Number of times downloaded

Tags: php, download, counter

How can I display a counter that counts the number of times a file is downloaded?  I've seen it before.  "Downloaded 450 times".  Thanks.

Comment: Pls let us know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't let the user download a file directly, but through a script like the following ...

```php
$file = $_REQUEST['file'];
$dldir = "downloads/";

if (
  (file_exists($dldir.$file) &&      // file exists
  (strpos($file, "../") === false))  // prevent an attacker from switching to a parent directory
) {

   header('Content-type: '.mime_content_type($dldir.file));
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header("Content-Length: " . filesize($dldir.$file) ."; "); 
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');

   echo file_get_contents($dldir.$file);

/** Update the counter here, e.g. by using mysql **/
} else {
   die("File not found");
}
```

Comment: Also be careful not to allow downloading files like /etc/passwd when creating custom download scripts.

Comment: I would SPECIFY which folder to get a file from, do not let (like Kaivos.. said) users hijack a file from you like /etc/passwd

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with PHP, you need to control the download in a PHP script. Basically it comes down to the following two lines of pseudo-code:

```
set_number_of_downloads(get_number_of_downloads() + 1);
readfile($file_being_downloaded);
```

Answer (score 1):

[There](http://www.willmaster.com/library/statistics/download-counter.php) you go.
Also, if you prefer using MySQL for persistence, there's [this](http://mikeleigh.com/dev/downloadcounter/) solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Apache you could have mod_rewrite update a database when the file is requested.  This has the advantage of speed in sending (sendfile can be used), and you don't have to change your URLs or directory structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1;
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:database=; host=localhost; user=; password=")
or die "Connecting from PHP to MySQL database failed: $DBI::errstr";
while (<STDIN>) {
    $dbh->query(... update database ...);
    print $_;
}
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine