# LAMP: Redirect file download requests to a php page to count file downloads

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Currently I have a client application which downloads files directly from my WEB server which is running on a LAMP server. File adresses are like this: `http://example.com/application/images/*.jpg`.

I'm going to count number of times file downloaded; However I cannot change client applications so they can send their request to other addresses or page.

I guess there are some techniques based on URL-rewriting so that I can convert request in form like `http://example.com/application/images/xyz.jpg` to something like `http://example.com/application/counter.php?file=xyz.jpg`. This way I can  handle file downloads and count them using techniques suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1630113/1080355).

So I want to know how should I setup `.htaccess` file or use mod-rewrtie to redirect my requests to `counter.php` page?

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

P.S. My web server is running on a shared host so I don't have access to everything on this server but I can do task like adding/editing `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(application)/images/(xyz\.jpg)$ $1/counter.php?file=$2 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Then inside `counter.php` keep a count and then load `jpg` image using `$_GET['file']` with correct MIME-TYPE.

Comment: The rewrite rule you didn't work. I've put my .htaccess file on site root here. May be it helps.